# Use constructor as predicate

Tags: c++

Can we use a constructor as predicate? So far what I manage to be able to do is this:

```
std::vector<const char*> v1 = {
    "Hello", "from", "GCC", __VERSION__, "!"
};
std::vector<std::string> v2(v1.size());
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
    [] (const char* s) { return std::string(s); });
```

But I want some way to do `std::tranform( ..., std::string)`. I've tried `std::string::string`, `std::string::basic_string` and `std::string::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: You can't do that with constructors. Why not just `vector<string> v2(v1.begin(), v1.end())`?

Comment: I also don't see a point for the use of `std::transform` in your question, are you actually having a XY-problem?

Comment: Pass the typename to a template, and use the typename to call the constructor?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Can we assume that the user simplified their code and that although we can't see the "need" here that it may still be there?

Comment: @MichaelGazonda That's why I've been asking about the XY-problem.

Comment: I think you mean functor not predicate; a predicate returns a bool.

Comment: This isn’t a predicate. A [predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3230944/1968) is a filter criterion. Specifically, it’s a function which takes one argument and returns a `bool`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You probably mean a value contextually convertible to `bool`. Because it needn't actually be `bool`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe that’s philosophical but I maintain that a true predicate (in CS) needs to return a boolean value, and that some functions simply perform this conversion for you. In the context of C++, it’s true that they neither need to be a function, nor that they need to return a `bool` and furthermore, the standard even knows something known as a “binary predicate”, which I find an odd extension of the term.

Answer (score 7):

I would just do:

```
std::vector<std::string> v2(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Comment: The easiest and simplest, which should be preferred until and unless some transformation is needed. In which case the range-for would win.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple

```
std::vector<std::string> v2;
v2.reserve(v1.size()); // Not really needed
for(auto x : v1) v2.emplace_back(x);
```

Comment: I heard that range-for loops cannot add contents to container.

Comment: They can. But if you are in a range-for-loop over a container, you 1) don't know which index the current element has and 2) must not invalidate the containers iterators, as range-for is iterator-based.

Comment: C++ Primer. Maybe my memory is not well.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Well it's not true. As Deduplicator said they can add elements but they are not without their pitfalls.

Comment: @Deduplicator You probably want to move the elements in: `v2.emplace_back(std::move(x))`.

Comment: Ok thanks @Deduplicator and @0x499602D2!, I probably need to do actual programming without just reading books :)

Comment: @0x499602D2: In this case, I don't actually want to move. In general, it's a worthwhile optimization though.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that we need to pass the `typename` to a `template`, and then we can use that to call the constructor that you want.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
template<typename source, typename destination, typename iter, typename iter2>
void transform_object(iter begin, iter end, iter2 begin2)
{
    std::transform(begin, end, begin2, [](source s){ return destination(s); } );
}
```

And to use it with your original code:

```
transform_object<const char*, std::string>(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin());
```

Comment: Why the struct with the static method? You can make it a free function template, you can also get the element type with `typename iter::value_type`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Fixed. Was getting used to structs for everything... ty for the catch.