# Split List By Value and Keep Separators

Tags: python

I have a list called `list_of_strings` that looks like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']
```

I want to split this list by a value (in this case `c`). I also want to keep `c` in the resulting split.

So the expected result is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c'], ['e']]]
```

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas Thanks for pinging me back. You're right, I just saw the main difference. I'll remove it.

Comment: You might want to look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`more_itertoools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.split_after)<sup>+</sup> to accomplish this simply and clearly:

```
from more_itertools import split_after


lst = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "c", "e"]
list(split_after(lst, lambda x: x == "c"))
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c'], ['e']]
```

---

Another example, here we split words by simply changing the [predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230944/what-does-predicate-mean-in-the-context-of-computer-science):

```
lst = ["ant", "bat", "cat", "asp", "dog", "carp", "eel"]
list(split_after(lst, lambda x: x.startswith("c")))
# [['ant', 'bat', 'cat'], ['asp', 'dog', 'carp'], ['eel']]
```

<sub><sup>+</sup> A third-party library that implements [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and more. `> pip install more_itertools`</sub>

Comment: This does only work for the special case of my example. It does not split on the value ``c``, but chunks the list equally.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas I see your requirements now.  This answer has been fixed using the same library.

Comment: You shouldn't use `is` to compare strings.

Comment: Thanks  for the feedback.

Comment: `pip install more-itertools`

Answer (score 6):

```
stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']
```

You can find out the indices with `'c'` like this, and add 1 because you'll be splitting after it, not at its index:

```
indices = [i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(stuff) if x == 'c']
```

Then extract slices like this:

```
split_stuff = [stuff[i:j] for i, j in zip([0] + indices, indices + [None])]
```

The `zip` gives you a list of tuples analogous to `(indices[i], indices[i + 1])`, with the concatenated `[0]` allowing you to extract the first part and `[None]` extracting the last slice (`stuff[i:]`)

Comment: Please provide some context and explanation for your answer. Code alone doesn't make for a great answer.

Comment: I understand - I added explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like the following:

```
list_of_strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']

output = [[]]

for x in list_of_strings:
    output[-1].append(x)
    if x == 'c':
        output.append([])
```

Though it should be noted that this will append an empty list to your output if your input's last element is `'c'`

Comment: Just move the appending of the empty list at the top of the `for` body, using a flag.  I have just posted a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591659/2749397) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def spliter(value, array):
    res = []
    while value in array:
        index = array.index(value)
        res.append(array[:index + 1])
        array = array[index + 1:]
    if array:
        # Append last elements
        res.append(array)
    return res

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']
print(spliter('b',a))
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']]
print(spliter('c',a))
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c'], ['e']]
```

Comment: now it looks better. You must have edited something. Dont remember any more. I did not dv anyway

Comment: Thanks :) After trying out this solution seems kind of slow, but it works as expected.

Comment: It will be slow. The `value in array` bit essentially makes it quadratic time. Instead you could just call array on progressively smaller slices and you could make it linear.

Comment: @PaulRooney yes, you can improve this part of code using `try except else` like someone describe here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list
But is it so necessary?

Comment: On my dataset this code takes 5 minutes versus the approved answer which takes 2 seconds.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas you are right, I wrote this snippet, not for big data sets :)  And I agree with you that approved answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about this. It should only iterate over the input once and some of that is in the `index` method, which is executed as native code.

```
def splitkeep(v, c):

    curr = 0
    try:
        nex = v.index(c)
        while True:
            yield v[curr: (nex + 1)]
            curr = nex + 1
            nex += v[curr:].index(c) + 1

    except ValueError:
        if v[curr:]: yield v[curr:]

print(list(splitkeep( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e'], 'c')))
```

result

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c'], ['e']]
```

I wasn't sure if you wanted to keep an empty list at the end of the result if the final value was the value you were splitting on. I made an assumption you wouldn't, so I put a condition in excluding the final value if it's empty.

This has the result that the input `[]` results in only `[]` when arguably it might result in `[[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this *rather playful* script:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']

b = ''.join(a).split('c')  # ['ab', 'ad', 'e']

c = [x + 'c' if i < len(b)-1 else x for i, x in enumerate(b)]  # ['abc', 'adc', 'e']

d = [list(x) for x in c if x]
print(d)  # [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c'], ['e']]
```

---

It can also handle beginnings and endings with a `"c"`

```
a = ['c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'c']
d -> [['c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c'], ['e', 'c']]
```

Comment: Thanks :) The problem with this solution is, because of joining the strings, this only works on chars and not generally on strings.

Comment: can you provide an example that would cause it to fail?

Comment: ``['a', 'cb', 'c', 'ca', 'aad', 'c', 'ccc', 'e']``, this is an example for what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']

value = 'c'
new_list = []
temp_list = []
for item in list_of_strings:
    if item is value:
        temp_list.append(item)
        new_list.append(temp_list[:])
        temp_list.clear()
    else:
        temp_list.append(item)

if (temp_list):
    new_list.append(temp_list)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below snippet. Use more_itertools

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']
>>> from more_itertools import sliced
>>> list(sliced(l,l.index('c')+1))
```

Output is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c'], ['e']]
```