# Python: How to split a list based on a specific element

Tags: python, list, indexing

If we have the following list in Python

```
sentence = ["I", "am", "good", ".", "I", "like", "you", ".", "we", "are", "not", "friends", "."]
```

How do I split this to get a list which contains elements that finish with the full stop? So i want to get the following elements in my new list:

```
["I","am","good","."]
["I","like","you","."]
["we","are","not","friends","."]
```

My attempts so far:

```
cleaned_sentence = []
a = 0
while a < len(sentence):
    current_word = sentence[a]
    if current_word == "." and len(cleaned_sentence) == 0:
        cleaned_sentence.append(sentence[0:sentence.index(".")+1])
        a += 1
    elif current_word == "." and len(cleaned_sentence) > 0:
        sub_list = sentence[sentence.index(".")+1:-1]
        sub_list.append(sentence[-1])
        cleaned_sentence.append(sub_list[0:sentence.index(".")+1])
        a += 1
    else:
        a += 1

for each in cleaned_sentence:
    print(each)
```

Running this on `sentence` produces

```
['I', 'am', 'good', '.']
['I', 'like', 'you', '.']
['I', 'like', 'you', '.']
```

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: Does the list always ends with the *separator*?

Comment: yes the list always ends with the separator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split List By Value and Keep Separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189895/split-list-by-value-and-keep-separators)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
i = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(sentence, key='.'.__ne__))
print([a + b for a, b in zip(i, i)])
```

This outputs:

```
[['I', 'am', 'good', '.'], ['I', 'like', 'you', '.'], ['we', 'are', 'not', 'friends', '.']]
```

If your list doesn't always end with `'.'` then you can use `itertools.zip_longest` instead:

```
sentence = ["I", "am", "good", ".", "I", "like", "you", ".", "we", "are", "not", "friends"]
i = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(sentence, key='.'.__ne__))
print([a + b for a, b in zip_longest(i, i, fillvalue=[])])
```

This outputs:

```
[['I', 'am', 'good', '.'], ['I', 'like', 'you', '.'], ['we', 'are', 'not', 'friends']]
```

Comment: I like `groupby` but I think using `operator.ne` is better than the dunder methods

Comment: `iter` should not be necessary. The generator expression constitutes an iterator already

Comment: also this assumes the last sentence ends with a full-stop otherwise the entire last sentence is missed (this might be a fair assumption)

Comment: @Chris_Rands You would have to wrap `operator.ne` with `partial` or use a lambda (which kinda sucks :) ), but I generally agree.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Indeed. I've updated my answer with a solution for that scenario then.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Indeed. I've updated my answer so it uses the generator expression as an iterator. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in two stages: first calculating the indices where the dots are located, and then making slices, like:

```
idxs = [i for i, v in enumerate(sentence, 1) if v == '.']   # calculating indices

result = [sentence[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+idxs, idxs)]    # splitting accordingly
```

This then yields:

```
>>> [sentence[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+idxs, idxs)]
[['I', 'am', 'good', '.'], ['I', 'like', 'you', '.'], ['we', 'are', 'not', 'friends', '.']]
```

You can then for example print the individual elements with:

```
for sub in [sentence[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+idxs, idxs)]:
    print(sub)
```

This then will print:

```
>>> idxs = [i for i, v in enumerate(sentence, 1) if v == '.']
>>> for sub in [sentence[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+idxs, idxs)]:
...     print(sub)
...
['I', 'am', 'good', '.']
['I', 'like', 'you', '.']
['we', 'are', 'not', 'friends', '.']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sentence = ["I", "am", "good", ".", "I", "like", "you", ".", "we", "are", "not", "friends", "."]

output = []
temp = []
for item in sentence:
    temp.append(item)
    if item == '.':
        output.append(temp)
        temp = []
if temp:
    output.append(temp)

print(output)
```

Comment: Brute force but still works. But not the python way. Better to use functionalities given in the python.

Comment: @Eswar: The solution is not brute-force, it is the best you could do and it only loops once. I think you refer to the fact that it contains more lines and doesn't use any libraries. IMO, which I find to be more readable in this case. Readability can mean different things to different folks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
sentence = ["I", "am", "good", ".", "I", "like", "you", ".", "we", "are", "not", "friends", "."]
last = len(sentence) - 1
result = [[]]
for i, v in enumerate(sentence):
    if v == ".":
        result[-1].append(".")
        if i != last:
            result.append([])
    else:
        result[-1].append(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['I', 'am', 'good', '.'], ['I', 'like', 'you', '.'], ['we', 'are', 'not', 'friends', '.']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer aims to be the simplest one...

The data

```
sentences = ["I", "am", "good", ".",
            "I", "like", "you", ".",
            "We", "are", "not", "friends", "."]
```

We initialize the output list and represent that we are **start**ing a new sentence

```
l, start = [], 1
```

We loop on the data list, using `w` to address the current word

- if we are at the start of a new sentence we clear the flag and add an empty list to the tail of the output list
- we append the current word to the last sublist (note that ① we are guaranteed that there is at least a last sublist (do you like alliterations?) and ② every word gets appended)
- if we are at the end — we have met a `"."` — we raise again the flag.

Note the single comment…

```
for w in sentences:
    if start: start = l.append([]) # l.append() returns None, that is falsey...
    l[-1].append(w)
    if w == ".": start = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by joining the elements together into a string and then splitting the string back again using a regex:

```py
import re

sentence = ["I", "am", "good", ".", "I", "like", "you", ".", "we", "are", "not", "friends", "."]
result = [m.split('\0') for m in re.findall(r'(?<=\0).*?\.(?=\0|$)', '\0'.join(['.']+sentence))]
```

Output:

```
[
 ['I', 'am', 'good', '.'],
 ['I', 'like', 'you', '.'],
 ['we', 'are', 'not', 'friends', '.']
]
```