# Python: split a list into multiple lists based on a specific element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I want to split the following list into sub lists based on an element from that list.

```
    array=['first','sentence','step','second','sentence']
    for i in array:
        if i!='step':
            newlist1.append(i)
        else:
            (stop appending in newlist1 and start appending in say newlist2)
```

newlist1 and newlist2 can not be pre declared. As the number of elements in the array can vary. SO I need to find a dynamic way of declaring lists as per the requirement.

Comment: should step be included in the second list?

Comment: no step is working as a separator element. It should preferably be removed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590886/python-how-to-split-a-list-based-on-a-specific-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a list of lists to store these. So if the value is step then start a new list, if not then append to the last list.

```py
from pprint import pprint

lists = [[]]
array = ['first', 'sentence', 'step', 'second', 'sentence', 'step', 'thrid', 'step', 'some', 'other', 'sentance']
for i in array:
    if i == 'step':
        lists.append([])
    else:
        lists[-1].append(i)
pprint(lists)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['first', 'sentence'],
 ['second', 'sentence'],
 ['thrid'],
 ['some', 'other', 'sentance']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
array=['first','sentence','step','second','sentence']
newlist1 = []
newlist2 = []
check = True
for i in array:
    if i!='step' and check:
        newlist1.append(i)
    else:
        check = False
        newlist2.append(i)
```

Comment: This doesn't adhere to the OPs requirements that: the new lists be created dynamically as the original is of arbitrary length. It also ignores the clarification comment that 'step' be removed from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
index = array.index('step') 
if index and index < len(array):
    newlist1 = array[0:index+1]
    newlist2 = array[index+1:]
```

Comment: This doesn't adhere to the OPs requirements that: the new lists be created dynamically as the original is of arbitrary length. It also ignores the clarification comment that 'step' be removed from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Although less memory efficient than Chris Doyle's answer, I prefer comprehensions for stuff like this unless they get too verbose to fit on one line.

```
array = ['first', 'sentence', 'step', 'second', 'sentence', 'step', 'third', 'step', 'some', 'other', 'sentence']

def split_list(lst, sep):
    return [i.split() for i in ' '.join(lst).split(sep)]

print(split_list(array, 'step'))
```

**Result**

```
[['first', 'sentence'], ['second', 'sentence'], ['third'], ['some', 'other', 'sentence']]
```

**Bonus**

If the end goal is a list of sentences instead of a list of lists, just replace the first `.split()` with `.strip()`.

```
[i.strip() for i in ' '.join(lst).split(sep)]
```

**Returns:**

```
['first sentence', 'second sentence', 'third', 'some other sentence']
```