# How to split a list using marker elements?

Tags: python, list, split, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm trying to split a list in Python using some elements as markers. For example, consider the list:

```py
["marker1", "elem1", "elem2", "marker2", "elem3"]
```

I wish to split it into 2 sublists:

```py
[["marker1", "elem1", "elem2"], ["marker2", "elem3"]]
```

If the first element is not a marker, the elements before the marker shall be considered as a separate sublist:

```py
# From:
["elem1", "elem2", "marker1", "elem3", "marker2", "elem4", "elem5"]
# To:
[["elem1", "elem2"], ["marker1", "elem3"], ["marker2", "elem4", "elem5"]]
```

It is easy to do using a regular loop:

```py
lst = ["elem1", "elem2", "marker1", "elem3", "marker2", "elem4", "elem5"]

separated = []
sub_lst = []
for elem in lst:
    if elem[:6] == "marker" and sub_lst:
        separated.append(sub_lst)
        sub_lst = []
    sub_lst.append(elem)
if sub_lst:
    separated.append(sub_lst)
```

This code is 9 lines long. My question is how to do that in one line (or so) using list comprehension or any other functional style. Any other elegant solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: Just curious - why you want to do `one-liner`?

Comment: Putting everything in one line would be hard

Comment: I don't like 9 lines of code. And I feel that functional style here would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create (and include) a new inner list at the start or at a marker, otherwise append to the current inner list ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7BCoMwDIbvPkXwooII6gZD2CvsBaSHgBFl2pY2MPf0XdtNdxjLIfxN8v399ZMnJduLNs4xWbZwhT4BX326ormTqdMSUlpoPUQTxHvZ7LM2FeUH@3dbf29/@dMuzsFIJMmoDCyWYZYQc3XRHX28m5IUH5Y0GmQaQmaEzvdNQAC3gEV6BKnYY2FYWUbD9jHzlGfv/7MibLBCrUkO@VaI6KzNLDk//AvnXg)):

```
a = None
separated = [a := [x] for x in lst if not a or x.startswith('marker') or a.append(x)]
```

Another ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5BCoMwELz7ipCLCiKoLZRCv9APhBwWjBiqSUgWal@fGlNTSts9LMPMzuyYB45adSdjvUfh0JELYRlZh9EZ7E3YhlaEiknMCbQBRLHduY7y6mX7d9u8b7/9hx0cQxDPskFbMjkkUpGt13lLd8KABRR9qhkGEgouCB521UrwD34J/BqZSDkQpXG9D2LtECy6u8SxyGO5vAwK1GCMUH2xlD/esIXHL3EbKxUWqWXp/RM)):

```
separated = [
    a
    for a in [None]
    for x in lst
    if not a or x.startswith('marker') or a.append(x)
    for a in [[x]]
]
```

Yet another (untested, can't test now):

```
from more_itertools import split_before

separated = list(split_before(lst, lambda s: s.startswith('marker')))
```

Comment: Good solution, but due to the walrus operator it works on Python 3.8+ only.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Which everybody should be using by now :-)

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Added a version without walrus.

Comment: `split_before` is what I was looking for. This is the most elegant solution that does exactly what I was requesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could look up the indexes of the `marker` elements in the list, and then take sublists based on those positions:

```py
lst = ["elem1", "elem2", "marker1", "elem3", "marker2", "elem4", "elem5"]
idxs = [i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if type(v) == str and v.startswith('marker')]
separated = [lst[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+idxs, idxs+[len(lst)]) if i < j]
# [['elem1', 'elem2'], ['marker1', 'elem3'], ['marker2', 'elem4', 'elem5']]

lst = ["marker1", "elem1", "elem2", "marker2", "elem3"]
idxs = [i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if type(v) == str and v.startswith('marker')]
separated = [lst[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+idxs, idxs+[len(lst)]) if i < j]
# [['marker1', 'elem1', 'elem2'], ['marker2', 'elem3']]
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591055/9473764).

Answer (score 0):

this is how `i` look like `[['elem1', 'elem2'],['marker1'],['elem3'],['marker2'],['elem4', 'elem5'],['marker3'],['elem6', 'elem7']]` but in a generator ofcourse

so we use `zip` and `i` as `generator` to compine every 2 lists together `['elem1', 'elem2'] + ['marker1']`

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = ["elem1", "elem2", "marker1", "elem3", "marker2", "elem4", "elem5", "marker3", "elem6", "elem7"]

i = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x.startswith('marker')))

print([a + b for a, b in zip(i, i)])
```

Edit1

```py
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest

lst = ["marker0", "elem1", "elem2", "marker1", "elem3", "marker2", "elem4", "elem5", "marker3", "elem6", "elem7"]

i = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x.startswith('marker')))

print([a + b for a, b in zip_longest(i, i, fillvalue=[])])
```

Edit2

```py
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest

lst = ["elem1", "elem2", "marker1", "elem3", "marker2", "elem4", "elem5", "marker3", "elem6", "elem7"]

i = iter([[]] + [list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x.startswith('marker'))])

print([a + b for a, b in zip_longest(i, i, fillvalue=[])])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591060/17246406

Comment: While markers are assigned to previous sublists instead of being headers for the next ones, the `groupby` is a good approach to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in case of no starting `marker`?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov adding a `'marker0'` at the beginning of the list will solve it

Comment: @DanielHao Thanks I didn't think of that, but i guess `zip_longest(i, i, fillvalue=[])` will do it

Comment: @AlbertoHanna, adding a `'marker0'` at the beginning of the list makes this solution less practical than a regular loop.