# Why are predicates for Rust iterator's FnMut and not Fn?

Tags: rust, iterator, predicate, type-signature

Looking at the predicates like `skip_while` and `take_while` they're

```
skip_while<P>(self, predicate P) -> ...
  where Self: Sized, P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool;
```

If a predicate is just returning true or false, and not modifying the values, why does it have to be `FnMut` and not `Fn` (like `Fn(&Self::Item) -> bool`)?

Comment: so you can have a state in your closure. FnMut mean it's allowed to mutate its state https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3fcda31e3bbe2fa974adaf92cd8d323b. as doc said "Use FnMut as a bound when you want to accept a parameter of function-like type and need to call it repeatedly, while allowing it to mutate state. If you don't want the parameter to mutate state, use Fn as a bound; if you don't need to call it repeatedly, use FnOnce." https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html

Answer (score 3):

The `Mut` in `FnMut` means that the predicate can have a mutable state. It says nothing about the parameters.

Additionaly, `FnMut` is a super-trait of `Fn`, so you can also pass an `Fn` where `FnMut` is accepted.

As a silly example, consider this closure that stores a state (hence is `FnMut`, but not `Fn`), but cannot modify the elements in the iterator:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7];

    println!("{:?}", v.iter().skip_while(|&&v| v != 0).collect::<Vec<_>>());

    let mut state = false;
    let one_after_zero = |&&v: &&u32| {
        if state {
            false
        } else if v == 0 {
            state = true;
            true
        } else {
            true
        }
    };

    println!("{:?}", v.iter().skip_while(one_after_zero).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a0745b5f17a4b62fc7ccae387932faf))

Output:

```
[0, 5, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I've never seen "predicate" refer to anything that had state. I guess it's just a definition but [it seems like a "predicate" here is any call back that returns a boolean, which seems to be the definition (according to stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344015/what-is-a-predicate) I wonder if `scan` is ever needed? Could you write something about how a predicate w/ state ties into scan?