# Test object in array for data-attr and return true/false if statement JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object array, and I want to test if one of them has a data-attr so I could make a simple if statement, here is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
if (array.hasAttribute("data-attr")) {}
```

I'm tried some() and every()

```
if (array.some(this.hasAttribute("data-attr"))) {}
```

but I can't figured out the right syntax, please help

Comment: What is the array of? jQuery objects? DOMElements?

Comment: @VLAZ DOM Elements

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: array some expects a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array.some(this.hasAttribute("data-attr"))
```

Was almost correct. [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) takes [a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344015/what-is-a-predicate), so you need to do

```
array.some(function(el) { 
  return el.hasAttribute("data-attr");
})
```

Or shorter using arrow functions:

```
array.some(el => el.hasAttribute("data-attr"))
```

[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) works the same way and takes a predicate, so you can call it the same way:

```
array.every(function(el) { 
  return el.hasAttribute("data-attr");
})
//or
array.every(el => el.hasAttribute("data-attr"))
```

And if you want to use one or the other, you can extract the predicate and re-use it:

```
var hasDataAttribute = el => el.hasAttribute("data-attr")

array.some(hasDataAttribute)
array.every(hasDataAttribute)
```

If you have jQuery objects, you have to use [some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097522/select-elements-by-attribute) since jQuery doesn't have a method that returns `true` or `false` for the existence attributes. You can easily simulate it with `obj.attr('some-attribute') !== undefined` - this will return `true` if `some-attribute` exists and `false` if it doesn't.

```
var hasDataAttribute = jQueryEl => jQueryEl.attr('data-attr') !== undefined
```

For `data-*` attriutes, you can also use [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which is (in this case) a shorthand `element.attr('data-something')` is the same as `element.data('something')`:

```
var hasDataAttribute = jQueryEl => jQueryEl.data('attr') !== undefined
```

Comment: Thank you, what do I have to change if it will be jQuery objects?

Comment: If `array` is a jQuery object, `array.filter('[data-attr]').length` is one approach @jay_dtr

Comment: Quick side note for the OP - just remember `some` only ensures that at least one element has that attribute, `every` requires that all elements do.

Comment: @jay_dtr added an approach for jQuery objects.