# how this specific code removes item from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn to react online and I understood everything except this line code

```
const removeItem = (id) => {
    let newPeople = people.filter((person) => person.id !== id);

    setPeople(newPeople);

  };
```

especially how `person.id !== id`removes the item from list and add to new list

here is the full code

```
import React from 'react';
import { data } from '../../../data';
const UseStateArray = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState(data);

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    let newPeople = people.filter((person) => person.id !== id);

    setPeople(newPeople);

  };
  return (
    <>
      {people.map((person) => {
        const { id, name } = person;
        return (
          <div key={id} className='item'>
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(id)}>remove</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button className='btn' onClick={() => setPeople([])}>
        clear items
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseStateArray;
```

Comment: `person.id !== id` isn't removing the item. `filter` function accepts a [predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344015/what-is-a-predicate) and only selects the items which when passed to the predicate, return `true`. In this case, `newPeople` is a list of people who's id is not the same as the `id` passed to the `removeItem` function.

Comment: These are just higher order array methods, I can't explain all of it in this comment, see: https://youtu.be/rRgD1yVwIvE?t=330

Answer (score 2):

first you shold khow how filter works,

The filter() method creates a new array filled with elements that pass a test provided by a function.

in your case test is `person.id !== id`,
if test passed for an element that element will be in new array.
otherwise element will not be in new array. is it clear?

Comment: ok I have difficulty understanding ES6 i like to know is `person.id !== id` and ` if(person.id !== id) ` are same

Comment: `person.id !== id`  and `if(person.id !== id){return true} else{return false}` are equal

Answer (score 0):

The filter method creates a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) of an array but not the whole array but only those elements that fulfills the predicate.

So `newPeople` will contain a copy of all the elements within `people` that it's `people[element].id` is different than `id`.

Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter for additional details of filter method.